# Get data from calendar of multiple office 365 users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to create an app that needs to retrieve data from multiple users calendars. Now, i'm still new to office 365 integration. i've found that you can use EWS managed Api for this. but i can't figure out how to actually get the data.
If someone could push me in the right direction, that would be awesome! I couldn't find any tutorial or simular that do these stuff.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try sofar?

Comment: i set up an office 365 developer account to try this. Trying to connect to it by using an exchangeservice but no luck yet.